# Why does var x: Float = 4.5 Throws an Error?

Tags: kotlin

Anybody know why does my code throw an error everytime i assign a floating type variable?

I expect it not to throw any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add F at the end of your code otherwise it will think that you are trying to assign a double

```
var x: Float = 4.5F
```

Answer (score 0):

`4.5` is `Double`,

`4.5f` is `Float`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Method 1: Convert Float to Double.

```
var x: Double = 4.5
```

Method 2: Add f or F at the end.

```
var x: Float = 4.5f
```

or

```
var x: Float = 4.5F
```